# Cannot connect to wifi with RTL8188CE - only LAN option shows up

Tags: drivers, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time.

I cannot connect to wifi because the only option available is LAN connection.

How can I fix this?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep 0280 -A3
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co, Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev01)
Devicename: Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [103c:1629]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce

$ modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Any time you ask a question, instead of posting a screenshot of your terminal, please copy the text, paste it into your question, and format is as code `{}` so that the text can be searched and copied etc :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wireless adapter is hard blocked.

You can do these steps to fix it:

1. Look if there is a hardware switch on your laptop and enable it.
2. Reset BIOS to defaults.

If 1 and 2 don't resolve the issue, run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: thank you... You're a Genius. I owe you some tacos and a few mojitos

Comment: What did solve the problem? And please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: i run the comand in the terminal ans reboot...